# Wordpress server change error

Tags: php, wordpress, installation

I uploaded my WordPress directory from localhost to server but the following error occurs

```
Warning: require_once(/home/greenvalleyfruits/greenvalleyfruits.com/sctc/wp-includes/wp-db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in/home/greenvalleyfruits/greenvalleyfruits.com/sctc/wp-includes/load.php on line 345`
```

---

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/greenvalleyfruits/greenvalleyfruits.com/sctc/wp-includes/wp-db.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear') in/home/greenvalleyfruits/greenvalleyfruits.com/sctc/wp-includes/load.php on line 345
```

Comment: Have you changed the site_url and home_url values to match the server?

Comment: Where do i change them.. I guess i already did.. My site is working now.. But i cannot login.. After login same page of login appears again and again

Comment: That error indicates the urls have not been updated. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress for different ways of doing it, a temporary solution would be defining them in wp-config just to see if that's the problem.

Comment: I tried it. How will i update all the links wothout error.. And what is rederict loop